# Can you format a Spanish time string (Java) to force AM/PM in caps?

Tags: java, android, datetime, time-format

In English the time format "h:mm a" gives "8:32 AM." In Spanish the same time format "h:mm a" gives me "8:32 a. m." Is there an easy way to format the Spanish to look like the English? Can you force a format to AM/PM in caps in Android/Java?

Answer (score 0):

**Easy solution**: Specify a locale that uses upper case AM and PM. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(Locale.US);
    
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(8, 32);
    
    String withUpperCaseAmPm = time.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(withUpperCaseAmPm);
```

Output is:

> 8:32 AM

I am of course using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

**Hard solution**: Specify the texts `AM` and `PM` explicitly.

```
    Map<Long, String> amPmTexts = new HashMap<>();
    amPmTexts.put(0L, "AM");
    amPmTexts.put(1L, "PM");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("h:mm ")
            .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, amPmTexts)
            .toFormatter();
```

When using this formatter instead output is the same as before.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.